# How does util:list behave with scope="prototype"?

Tags: java, spring

If I use the following Spring XML config, what will be the result if I assign the resulting bean to multiple properties?

```
<util:list id="myBeanId" scope="prototype">
  <bean class="com.mypackage.MyTestBeanClass1" />
  <bean class="com.mypackage.MyTestBeanClass2" />
</util:list>
```

As far as I can see, there are two possible outcomes:

- Multiple lists are created, but the beans inside them are shared (because their scope defaults to singleton)
- Multiple lists are created, and a new copy of each bean is created for each list instance

Also, what about this scenario?

```
<bean id="referencedBean" class="com.mypackage.MyTestBeanClass1" />
<util:list id="myBeanId" scope="prototype">
  <ref bean="referencedBean" />
  <bean class="com.mypackage.MyTestBeanClass2" />
</util:list>
```

This seems to offer additional possibilities:

- The `referencedBean` remains a singleton, but multiple instances of `MyTestBeanClass2` are created.
- Both `referencedBean` and `MyTestBeanClass2` are duplicated for each instance of the list created (this strikes me as unlikely, but still plausible).

I don't seem to be able to find any discussion of this in the spring docs.  In fact, as far as I can see, the existence of the scope property on util:list isn't even mentioned in the docs.  Have I missed it, or is this entirely undocumented?  If so can/should I rely on any particular behaviour?

Comment: Good question. I have used util:list many times but not in this way. I think multiple lists should be created, and all of these list would share the bean instances.

Comment: You can find it in spring documentation at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/xsd-config.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spring documentation for [Bean scopes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes) describes a good way of looking at it:

> When you create a bean definition, you create a recipe for creating actual instances of the class defined by that bean definition. The idea that a bean definition is a recipe is important, because it means that, as with a class, you can create many object instances from a single recipe.

So, whether you define a bean with `<bean>` or `<util:list>`, you are still just creating a reusable recipe. The `scope` attribute determines whether the recipe is *actually* reused.

**Example**

In this example context I define two recipes:

- `singleBean` with the default singleton scope
- `aList` with prototype scope

```
<bean id="singleBean" class="org.example.SingleBean" />

<util:list id="aList" scope="prototype">
    <value>some string value</value>
    <bean class="org.example.TestBean" />
    <ref bean="singleBean" />
</util:list>
```

Now I run this test application:

```
List<?> list = context.getBean("aList", List.class);
List<?> list2 = context.getBean("aList", List.class);

System.out.println(list);
System.out.println(list2);
System.out.println(list == list2);
```

Since `aList` is prototype, every time I ask for it spring runs the recipe again.

- `TestBean` is part of the recipe for the list so a new `TestBean` will be created each time.
- `<ref>` is a reference to *another recipe* with a separate scope value. The first time aList is created, the recipe for singleBean will be followed and the result will be cached in the context (since it's scope singleton). Subsequent runs of the aList recipe will cause the same singleBean value to be looked up.

The output of the program looks like this:

```
[some string value, org.example.TestBean@195198e8, org.example.SingleBean@3c0db454]
[some string value, org.example.TestBean@27ba1599, org.example.SingleBean@3c0db454]
false
```

Two different lists with two different TestBeans but only one SingleBean.

Basically, `util:list` is nothing special. If you made a class with 3 properties and used it instead of `util:list` in the above example, the result would be the same.

Comment: Good explanation, thanks.  And exactly the way I intuitively expected it to work, just I couldn't really find confirmation of it. :)